# How to use "mini_backtrace" Gem on rails 4.2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I followed Michael Hartl tutorial and now I'm developing my own app.
When I was making my first **RED** test I saw a **huge backtrace**, so I remembered to add "***mini_backtrace***" gem (v 0.1.3) to my Gemfile, and the difference was evident, backetraces were significantly reduced. Anyway I realize that adding the line

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| line =~ /rvm/ }
```

on *../config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb* file, didn't make any difference. I expected after commenting that line to see again the huge backtrace, but that just didn't happen.
Am I missing something? How should I use "*mini_backtrace*"?

I'm using rails 4.2.0 and my development OS is ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and the answer below has not worked.  Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html

I'm not sure why this `mini_backtrace` gem has been included to Hartl tutorial. Looks like the silencer's been a built-in since rails 2.3

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f42c77f927eb49b00e84d355e07de48723d03fcb

Edit: for Hartl tutorial, you already have included `minitest_reporters` gem, you may silence the noisy backtrace by following documentation https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters. Add lines to `test/test_helper.rb` file:

```
Minitest::Reporters.use!(
  Minitest::Reporters::DefaultReporter.new,
  ENV,
  Minitest.backtrace_filter
)
```

Comment: change the first parameter of the `use!` method to get different style of reporters. for example I use `Minitest::Reporters::ProgressReporter.new` for a progress bar. See the documentation linked in this answer for more.